# Loading an external SWF App in a new Air window with resize functionality

Tags: apache-flex, flash, air

i'm trying to load a local SWF Application in my Air Application via the SWFLoader class. The `SWFLoader` class is displayed in a new `Window`. Therefore, i'm trying to resize the window automatically, when the Flash Application is resizing. But here's the problem. The SWFLoader does not get any events when the loader App has been resized.

The Problem seems to be the Sandbox Restrictions. I'm able to call methods in the `childSandboxBridge` and `parentSandboxBridge` Objects that i've set in the `LoaderInfo` of the SWFLoaders content (the loaded SWF Application). But i cannot listen to any ResizeEvents or something like that when i'm resizing the loaded App.

I'm aware of the workaround with the `Loader` Class and the codeExecution Property, but i don't want to bypass the Air Sandbox - if possible.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note: other security sandbox issues may be part of your problems.  That said...)
IF your sandboxBridge is set and you can call methods though it as you mentioned, then you can dispatch and listen for events that bubble up through the swfLoader (and they do bubble through).

As a test I would try dispatching a test flash.events.Event with bubbles=true when your loaded swf captures its internal resizeEvent.  (ResizeEvents, by default, do not bubble and could be the source of your issue).

Comment: "(ResizeEvents, by default, do not bubble and could be the source of your issue)." Ah ok, that may be indeed the problem.

I've solved this with a workaround, where i'm listening to the ResizeEvent in the loaded App and call a function to resize in the parentSandboxBridge Object. But i will give your tip a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I find this way, putting it in childSwf:

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED,added)

function added(e){
    if (root.parent.parent){
    root.parent.parent.stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, mainResizeHandler);
}

function mainResizeHandler(e:Event = null):void{
    trace("width: "+stage.stageWidth+" | height"+stage.stageHeight);
}
```